# $P$ is a point inside the triangle $ABC$, from which perpendiculars intersect the sides $BC$ $AC$ $AB$ to the points...

Tags: euclidean-geometry

$P$ is a point inside the triangle $ABC$, from which perpendiculars intersect the sides $BC$ $AC$ $AB$ to the points $D'$, $E'$, $Z'$. If $AD$, $BE$, $CZ$ are the heights prove that $$ \frac{PD'}{AD}+\frac{PE'}{BE}+\frac{PZ'}{CZ}=1.$$

[image]

I believe it solved using similar triangles and Thales's theorem, but it didn't lead me anywhere.

Comment: Hint: $$\frac{|PD'|}{|AD|}= \frac{\frac12|BC|\cdot|PD'|}{\frac12|BC|\cdot|AD|}=\frac{|\triangle PBC|}{|\triangle ABC|}$$

Comment: Thank you! I didn't think of that!